# How to include <div> labels when converting SVG to PNG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, svg

SVG newbie here. I'm trying to do an enhancement wherein country labels (as `<div>`) are included during conversion of an SVG map to PNG.

The map to be converted looks like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the DOM. `div` labels to be included are highlighted.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var svg = $('svg', $(svgParentId));

// append map labels                                          // From this line...
var outerHtmlColl = $(svgParentId).find('.marker-label');     //
                                                              //
_.forEach(outerHtmlColl, function(item){                      //  
    svg = svg.append(item.outerHTML);                         //
});                                                           // ...to this line

// check whether style should be applied
if (styleSheet) {
    var styles = loadStyles([styleSheet]);

    var defs = $('defs', svg);
    if (!defs.length) {
        svg.prepend('<defs></defs>');
        defs = $('defs', svg).first();
    }

    var style = $('style', defs);
    if (!style.length) {
        defs.prepend('<style type="text/css"></style>');
        style = $('style', defs).first();
        style.html(styles);
    }
}

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svg[0]);

var canvas = $('#hiddenCanvas')[0];
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

canvg(canvas, svgStr,
    {
        ignoreDimensions: true, //does not try to resize canvas
        scaleWidth: width,
        scaleHeight: height,
        renderCallback: function () {
            var pngImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            func(pngImg.substring(22));
        }
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as seen below:

[image]

I'm not sure exactly what I'm missing here (or if this is possible at all...). Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a bad practice to me. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Your divs are not part of the svg - just include them below the new image?  Also, I don't think you can append divs to an svg. Any reason for the conversion?

Comment: Hi @Pete, thanks for replying. So it's technically not possible? If that's the case, would replacing `<div>` with `<g>` work? I haven't worked with SVG before this, so I'm working with what I understood so far...

Edit: I suggested the replacement with `<g>` because I saw that `<g>` was listed as a child when I inspected the DOM.

Comment: SVG is an image element / image manipulation element, it is pretty self contained and is scalable so again I ask the question, any reason to convert it to a png?

Comment: For sharing purposes. The page has a feature wherein users can share the map image in the site's Forums as a post. It also has an option to export the map as a PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Div's are not valid SVG sub-elements, so moving them into the SVG won't work.

You should move the text in the div's into the SVG by converting the div elements to `<text>` elements. Use the text elements' x and y attributes to position the label within the SVG.